# How to convert a large string data array from file to np.array with float data type

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

My task is to direct a potentially large set of elements for training a neural network. I am trying to use tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset and tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset but I keep getting stuck.

My dataset is a text file containing strings with numbers separated by ';'. This is how it looks:

```
14;14;14;55;55;20;20...33;34;34
20;20;20;15;15;15;26...10;10;10
....
10;10;10;30;30;35;35...23;23;23
```

Each line contains 2500 numbers, separated by each other. I tried to use this code

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(pathAsk,
                                          record_defaults=[tf.float32],
                                          field_delim=";",
                                          na_value='NA'
                                          )

for element in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
  print(element)
```

But I get an error like there are more elements in the row than I specified in record_defaults. Also I try to use this:

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(pathAsk, batch_size=2, field_delim=';')
iterator = dataset.as_numpy_iterator()
print(dict(next(iterator)))
```

But I get error:

```
Cannot have duplicate column names.
```

My task is to use this dataset so that it can get into the input of a neural network built in a similar way:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2500), name="ask")
x = keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 64)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=keras.activations.relu)(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=keras.activations.relu)(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(6, activation=keras.activations.relu)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile("adam", "binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found the answer to my question.
I added an indication of the number of dimensions of the row in the record_defaults property.

```
datasetAsk = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
    pathAsk,
    record_defaults = [tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)] * 2500,
    header = False,
    field_delim = ";",
    )
```

As a result, the number of elements in a line corresponds to the number of data types dtype and the iteration operation passes without errors.